# Navigate to a div on a different page with smooth scrolling

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to do smooth scroll while clicking the `a` elements in `.panel` class. It was redirecting to the coressponding id. But smooth scroll doesn't works.

**index.php**

```
<div class="panel">
    <p><a href="gallary.php#singleclr_led">SINGLE COLOUR LED</a></p>
    <p><a href="gallary.php#doubleclr_led">TWO COLOUR LED</a></p>
    <p><a href="gallary.php#multiclr_led">MULTI COLOUR LED</a></p>
    <p><a href="gallary.php#indoor_led">INDOOR LED DISPLAY</a></p>
    <p><a href="gallary.php#outdoor_led">OUTDOOR LED DISPLAY</a></p>
</div>
```

**jquery**

```
$('.panel a').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $(this).attr('href') ).offset().top
    }, 500);
    return false;
});
```

**gallary.php**

```
 <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 gallary-img1" id="multiclr_led">
                <div class="hovereffect">
                    <img src="images/colorimg.jpg" class="img-responsive "alt="">
                    <div class="overlay">
                        <h2>MULTI COLOUR LED</h2>
                        <div class="hover-content">
                            <P>6 colors are possible like in addition to RGB, they are cyan, magenta & yellow. This property is well utilized by the motherboard manufacturer, to show the power indication, RED means lower power than the recommended rating, green means ambient power etc. So they compacted the space requirements.</P>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Can't find the problem. Help this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So you are in a different page (let's name it `index.php`), and you want to open a new page (`gallery.php`), with smooth scrolling to the corresponding id?

Comment: Yes you are right @andreivictor

Comment: Can you also tell us how the target HTML will look like. Is it something like `<div id="singleclr_led">...` and is the panel only in `index.php` or also in `gallery.php`?

Comment: see Updated question @caramba

Answer (score 1):

Try with the following code (put it in `gallery.php` file):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var anchor = window.location.hash;

    if ( $(anchor).length > 0 ) {

        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(anchor).offset().top
        }, 500);

    }
});
```

Comment: What i have to do if i have common jquery file

Comment: Well, the code works even if it's placed in a common jquery file. But it will scroll smooth to all the anchors, even if they aren't inside the `gallery.php` file.

Comment: Do you have a link with your project so I can check it?